# Order of operations problem possibly, not seeing why this isn't printing desired output. Need clarification

Tags: java, math

The variable gallonsLeft are not actually being used, it's just to show why one set up is working and the other doesn't. See comment in code. On a calculator I get the same outputs, not sure why I don't in the program. Maybe something to do with data type used? idk...

```
    System.out.println("Tank Capacity: ");
    int tankTotal = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Gauge reading: ");
    int userGauge = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Miles per gallon: ");
    int mpg = input.nextInt();

    int gallonsLeft = ((userGauge * tankTotal)/100); // This prints out the correct number 
    int gallonsLeft = ((userGauge/100)* tankTotal); // This prints out 0
    System.out.println(gallonsLeft);
```

Comment: Integer division. Oops.

Comment: What does your calculator give for `((userGauge/100)* tankTotal)`?

Comment: Promote one of the operands to a double or float to perform floating point division: `((userGauge/100.0)* tankTotal)`

Comment: Did you check to see what `userGauge/100` is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem because (userGauge/100) result is not int. The int part is zero so you need to choose another datatype for this :

```
double gallonsLeft = ((userGauge/100)* tankTotal); // This prints out now the correct number
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. To confirm, if I'm using an int variable, all parts of my arithmetic has to always remain as integers? I figured I could use double but the practice problem I'm doing requires me to use only integers.